# Is there a way to create tablespace in MySQL RDS

Tags: mysql-5.7, amazon-rds

I'm using AWS RDS MySQL instance and using it. Now I want to create table space and assign table space to tables. Is it possible in MySQL RDS

Comment: What does Amazon documentation say? What are you trying to achieve by creating a separate tablespace?

Comment: I want to store old tables in one data file and movie it to S3 Glacier.is it possible?

Comment: any luck on this?